# Rendering Android layouts with React Native

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

I've added React Native to an existing Android project which has various layouts and fragments defined. Is there some easy way to reference a layout or fragment from JavaScript? Instead of rendering React Native components, can we render an existing Android layout?

So far the only way I've found to accomplish this was to have a custom module call within render, and then have it return false. The custom call would do this:

```
@ReactMethod
public void doSomething() {
    final Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    if (currentActivity != null) {
        UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                currentActivity.setContentView(R.layout.login_fragment_layout);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Which feels a little hacky. Is there a better way? Note: I do want the React Native context available so that I can integrate with a JavaScript library.